# "Open Admin Powershell here" Windows Explorer Context Menu

Tags: powershell, registry, contextmenu

I wanted to add an item to the windows explorer context menu, that would open a PowerShell as Admin.

---

I found this command which starts the powershell in the cmd:

```
PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -Command `"Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/s,/k,pushd,%V && PowerShell' -Verb RunAs`"
```

The problem with this is that the window is the cmd window and not the powershell one.

---

So I tried to make a command on my own and came up with this:

```
PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoExit -Command "Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList @(`'-NoExit`',`'-Command`',`'Set-Location -LiteralPath `"%V`"`')";
```

which works fine when executed in the cmd or powershell, but when i put it into the registry (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PowershellMenu (Administrator)\command\(Default)`) the powershell window flashes shortly.

---

I tried to...

...use the full PowerShell path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoExit -Command "Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList @(`'-NoExit`',`'-Command`',`'Set-Location -LiteralPath `"%V`"`')";
```

...add a sleep to see if the `-NoExit` is ignored:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -NoExit -Command "Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList @(`'-NoExit`',`'-Command`',`'Set-Location -LiteralPath `"%V`"; Sleep 10`')";
```

without any success.

Answer (score 0):

> Execute in PowerShell as administrator:

```
'Directory',
'Directory\Background',
'Drive' | ForEach-Object {
  $Path = "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\$_\shell\runas";
  New-Item -Path $Path -Name 'command' -Force | Out-Null;
  Set-ItemProperty -Path "$Path\command" -Name '(default)' -Value "PowerShell -WindowStyle Maximized -NoExit -NoLogo -Command Set-Location '%V'";
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name '(default)' -Value 'PowerShell';
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name 'HasLUAShield' -Value '';
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name 'Icon' -Value "${Env:WinDir}\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe,0";
}
```